# Prove that $a = b^m$ if $\frac{a^n-1}{b^n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Few weeks ago I asked this problem in math.stackexchange.com. I got one answer, but soution mentioned in this answer uses only for big natural numbers.
So thought about write this problem there.
$$a = b^m$$ if $\displaystyle\frac{a^n-1}{b^n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}  $ , $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

This problem drives me crazy for a month. Help.

Comment: $a=1+k(b^n-1)$?

Comment: Quantifiers are missing in your problem.

Comment: Various solutions and references are available at http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t116f6h4556_a_masterpiece

Comment: What does m equal to?

Comment: The earlier question was presumably http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919550/if-fracan-1bn-1-is-a-natural-number-for-every-n-then-a-bm, which was closed as a duplicate.